# cout corrupt char*

Tags: c++, char, garbage

I have written a code to print the name of 2 workers, but instead it prints garbage.

```
cout << "highest salary: " << highestSalary.getID() << " " << highestSalary.getName() << endl;

cout << "hardest worker: " << mostHours.getID() << " " << mostHours.getName();
```

the function getName() is defined in the worker class as:

```
char* Worker::getName()
{
    char temp[20];

    int i;
    strcpy(temp, name);

    return temp;
}
```

going through this on the debugger I tried putting the value of highestSalary.getName() inside a ver char* temp, and the value was what i anticipated, let's say "bob", but after the cout the value was "" and the cout printed garbage.

Comment: This behavior is SO undefined ;)

Comment: Hint: `std::string` is tremendously helpful for, lets say, everything that has to do with characters.

Comment: Why can't you friggin' google it? Seriously... This is asked like twice a day... Couldn't you just find one of the previous questions? Why? *Why?* ***Why?***

Comment: Buffer overflow fail. Lack of `std::string` fail. Getter fail. Everything fail.

Comment: Here's the main dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to a local variable. Once your function ends, this variable is gone.

If this is C++ you should use the string class. If for whatever reason you don't, at least be [const correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness):

```
const char* Worker::getName() const 
{
    return name;
}
```

Comment: The const after the function name means that this function will not alter the state of the class instance it's called on.

Answer (score 8):

NO NO NO, you are returning a pointer to a local function variable.  That's why it crashes.

Do this instead:

```
std::string Worker::getName()
{
   std::string temp(name); // not sure what type of name is...
   return temp;
}
```

Don't forget to `#include<string>`.

Now you have real C++, not C and pointers.

Comment: I'm a student and had yet to learn the string class.